# Create a branch in Git at a specific point in time

Tags: git, branch

We have identified an issue in our production code.  But several merges to Master have happened since the release.  No tag or branch was made at the time of release.  But we know when the release build started.

When I used TFS, I could just pick a point in time and create a branch from that point.

**How can I do that in Git?**

Comment: Do you know the commit id of the release?

Comment: @tkausl - yes I do

Comment: Well... `git branch name-of-branch id-of-revision`

Comment: Checkout that commit and create a branch there. Now when you commit it will use that commit as the parent.

Comment: or `git checkout-b name-of-branch id-of-revision` if you want to create the branch and checkout in a single shot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find your *commit* where you want to create a new branch:

`git log`

With this *commit-id* you can create a branch with the version of this commit-id:

`git branch <branch-name> <commit-id>`

---

You can also use

`git checkout <commit-id>`

that will bring you to the version of this commit-id, after this create a branch with

`git branch <branch-name>`

and then go to this created branch (*checkout*)

`git checkout <branch-name>`

This two steps, can be done in one:

`git checkout -b <branch-name>`